# Composer update doesn't work in my case

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I installed Laravel 5.0 at my websites (via FTP). Then I tried to connect via SSH and update using Composer. However I am getting this error. (My PHP is version 5.5, I checked the phpinfo function).

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: argv in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 55
PHP Warning:  array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 59
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285



  [ErrorException]                         
  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  



X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.28
Content-type: text/html

Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI

Notice: Undefined index: argv in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 55

Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 59

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285
```

I controlled cli -v , I getting this command not found.

Later I tried below:

```
$ php -d register_argc_argv=1 "./composer.phar" install

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - league/flysystem 1.0.16 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.28) or value of "config.platform.php" in composer.json does not satisfy that requirement.
    - league/flysystem 1.0.16 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.28) or value of "config.platform.php" in composer.json does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for league/flysystem 1.0.16 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.16].
```

Comment: I had problem with updating composer also, found later that you need at least 768 MB or RAM  to do such a command, when I updated my hosting everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is the important error:

> Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI

Try `which php` to see where your PHP binary is pointing, and then `locate bin/php` to find out what other versions you have your system.

Also note this:

> My PHP is version 5.5; I checked the phpinfo function

Something disagrees with you:

> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.28

Try other copies of your PHP binary, discovered with `locate`, using the fully-qualified path. For example:

```
/usr/bin/php55-cli composer.php update
```

If this host has a 5.5 CGI binary and a 5.3 console binary, it is possible they do not know what they are doing - 5.3 should no longer be supported these days. If you do not have any luck fixing it yourself, create a support ticket and ask for `php` to invoke the 5.5 console binary from the shell.

---

Update: following from the conversation in the comments, it looks like the above has fixed one problem and exposed another. The new problem is that your Composer command is getting further, and it is trying to invoke a PHP helper that uses the `php` binary again. This then causes the original problem (it's the web server binary, and it's 5.3 rather than 5.5).

To resolve this, I suggest you (a) create a local `php` executable to point to the version you want, and then (b) reset the system path. I would try the following, in your project directory:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/php55-cli ./php
PATH=. ./php composer.phar update
```

What this will do is create a symbolic link to the version of PHP that you want, and then reset the system path temporarily to just the current directory.

If this does not fully resolve the issue, you may need to put your symlink in a more permanent place (e.g. `~/bin/php` and modify your shell start-up file. Please be willing to play around with this before exclaiming that it does not work - the best way to learn how to do this independently is to try!

Comment: when I run 'which php' output is /usr/bin/php . And run /usr/bin/php composer.php update. Again same error

Comment: @Kerim: see the last paragraph for what to do in that eventuality.

Comment: When I runned locate bin/php   /usr/bin/php
/usr/bin/php4
/usr/bin/php5
/usr/bin/php5-cli
/usr/bin/php53
/usr/bin/php53-cli
/usr/bin/php54
/usr/bin/php54-cli
/usr/bin/php55
/usr/bin/php55-cli
/usr/bin/phpize54
/usr/bin/phpize55

Comment: Great, @Kerim! Which one do you think would be appropriate, given that (a) you want the CLI version, and (b) you want the 5.5 version?

Comment: @halter When I run it /usr/bin/php55 composer.phar install                      X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
Content-type: text/html

Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI

Notice: Undefined index: argv in phar:///home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 55                                                                                      if I cli version run -> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-install-cmd event returned with an error

Comment: Yes, that's the same problem @Kerim. Try the `/usr/bin/php55-cli` version? "CLI" means "command line interpreter" i.e. this would be the correct version to use on the console.

Comment: @halter: [kerimcaglar.com@sharedssh0 laravel]$ /usr/bin/php55-cli composer.phar update
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/cluster-sites/58/kerimcaglar.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 50
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.28
Content-type: text/html              Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error

Comment: Oh dear @Kerim - it looks like one problem has been fixed and then another one pops up in its place. It looks like you have a helper file that requires `php` to point to the correct version. I'll update my post.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The problem was pre and post composer commands. I changed the commands like "php artisan optimize" to "/usr/bin/php55-cli artisan optimize". That solved my problem. Thanks for your time again.

Comment: @Kerim, thanks for that information, and you are welcome. Pleased it is now fixed for you.